# what's the best way to keep passing the pattern when you encounter a character like "á" with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

for example I would liked to take the number 1, in this example but the question is how to by pass "Páginas" or 'á', 'é', 'ó'...

[example in regex.com](https://regexr.com/6bper)

I too would like to see a complete example with php...
I got by pass with this, but I thought that it isn't the best way

```
$pattern = '#P.ginas\sde Resultados(.*?)<\/font>#is';
echo preg_match($pattern, $subject, $result).PHP_EOL;
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Use the u modifier, with it the dot matches code points instead of bytes. Use regex101.com

Comment: how can I use it?

Comment: The question is to match characters regardless of accents? Regex don't have collation/charsets as a DB would. You need to define the possible characters. `P[áéóa]ginas` for example would achieve what you asked. You could swap the chars to their latin version and see if they match. There are a few threads about that already most refer to `iconv`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't believe `u` would achieve what OP wants in this case.

Comment: I tried this 
`$pattern = '/P[á]ginas(.*?):/';`, in site regex.com it works, but in my test code it not working.

Comment: When I used this pattern 
`$pattern = '/P.ginas(.*?):/';`
I got this result:
`Array ( [0] => P�ginas de Resultados: [1] => de Resultados )`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte how can I use this u modifier? do you have any example.

Comment: `u` stands for UTF-8. If your source code is saved in some legacy encoding like ISO-8859-1 this is not going to work (but it should work without the flag).

Comment: I am brazillian, then I thought that should be commom ISO-8859 but I'm build the crawler/bot, if I am have different result, I thought that I must change the charset of my file index.php, or maybe look better the my subject is using any different charset.

Comment: How many ways is Paginas spelled with Brazilian Portuguese? If you are parsing valid HTML documents, regex is rarely the right tool.  You may wish to see some DOMDocument with XPath pages on Stack Overflow which demonstrate how to collect all of the `<b>` values within the context of your targeted `<font>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for passing any character is using the same character then:
Use `á`, but use inside `'//'` instead of `'##is'`.

For example: `$pattern = '/Páginas\sde\sResultados(.*?)<\/font>/';`